# How to connect to a MongoDB in React, Typescript using Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, docker-compose

I have a web app in on container, and mongoDB running in another. I would like to use mongoDB as the backend for my webapp but I can't seem to connect the two.

I am using docker compose to run both from one command.

Using `mongoose.connect()` threw errors because of typescript, and `mongodb.MongoClient()` gave 'ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined'. Does anyone know of a working method to connect to a MongoDB in this scenario?

`import mongoose from 'mongoose'`

shows "Could not find a declaration file for module 'mongoose'" even though its npm installed and in package.json.

I know the ports are visible because I can access both through the browser.

`const mongoose = require('mongoose');` can't find package mongoose

I think I have some nasty mess of dependencies which may be messing everything up.

Thank you for any help

---

current index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
import * as Mongoose from "mongoose";
//const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//var db = new mongodb.MongoClient('mongodb://nosnes');
//var mongoclient = new mongodb.MongoClient('mongodb://mongo:27017',{} );
var uri = 'mongodb://mongo:27017';
Mongoose.connect(uri);
// //Mongoose.connect(uri, {
//   useNewUrlParser: true,
//   useFindAndModify: true,
//   useUnifiedTopology: true,
//   useCreateIndex: true,
// });


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

current error

[image: current error]

Comment: Please share more code because it sounds like you're trying to connect to mongo directly from the the front end which is isn't usually possible or advised.

Comment: @zero98 that is exactly what I am trying to do, didn't know this wasn't advised. What is the workaround? My database calls have been occurring in index.tsx. Will share more shortly

Comment: The idea is that you have an API server that your front-end makes calls to and that API server is what connects to the DB.